# Remove duplicate phrases

Tags: java, string, duplicates

How can i remove duplicate phrases? I want to generate name form 2 strings, but without duplicate phrases.

Condition:

1. Don't remove duplicate from the same string. I mean:

```
String s1 = "duplicate duplicate duplicate"
String s2 = "xyz"
afterRemovedDuplicates = "duplicate duplicate duplicate xyz"
```

2. Remove phrases ONLY when phrases occur one after another

```
String s1 = "duplicate phrases"
String s2 = "duplicate phrases abcd"
afterRemovedDuplicates = "duplicate phrases abcd"
```

but also it can be a part of phrases(ONLY when phrases occur one after another)

```
String s1 = "duplicate phrases"
String s2 = "phrases abcd"
afterRemovedDuplicates = "duplicate phrases abcd"
```

So if we have

```
String s1 = "duplicate phrases x"
String s2 = "duplicate phrases abcd"
afterRemovedDuplicates = "duplicate phrases x duplicate phrases abcd"
```

Remove duplicates should do nothing because "x" is between phrases.

Comment: Where did you get stuck in your attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried use regex, but this remove also phrases from te same string. I cant simply split strings, because it can phrase not single word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
static String removeDuplicatePhrase(String s1, String s2) {
    s1 = s1.trim(); s2 = s2.trim();
    List<String> list1 = List.of(s1.split("\\s+"));
    List<String> list2 = List.of(s2.split("\\s+"));
    int size1 = list1.size(), size2 = list2.size();
    int i = Math.min(size1, size2);
    for (; i > 0; --i)
        if (list1.subList(size1 - i, size1).equals(list2.subList(0, i)))
            break;
    return String.join(" ", list1) + " " + String.join(" ", list2.subList(i, size2));
}

static void test(String s1, String s2) {
    System.out.println("s1     = " + s1);
    System.out.println("s2     = " + s2);
    System.out.println("result = " + removeDuplicatePhrase(s1, s2));
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("duplicate duplicate duplicate", "xyz");
    test("duplicate phrases", "duplicate phrases abcd");
    test("duplicate phrases", "phrases abcd");
    test("duplicate phrases x", "duplicate phrases abcd");
    test("duplicate phrases", "duplicate phrases");
    test("duplicate ph", "duplicate phrases");
    test("duplicate phrases", "phrases");
    test("duplicate phrases", "rases");
}
```

output:

```
s1     = duplicate duplicate duplicate
s2     = xyz
result = duplicate duplicate duplicate xyz

s1     = duplicate phrases
s2     = duplicate phrases abcd
result = duplicate phrases abcd

s1     = duplicate phrases
s2     = phrases abcd
result = duplicate phrases abcd

s1     = duplicate phrases x
s2     = duplicate phrases abcd
result = duplicate phrases x duplicate phrases abcd

s1     = duplicate phrases
s2     = duplicate phrases
result = duplicate phrases 

s1     = duplicate ph
s2     = duplicate phrases
result = duplicate ph duplicate phrases

s1     = duplicate phrases
s2     = phrases
result = duplicate phrases 

s1     = duplicate phrases
s2     = rases
result = duplicate phrases rases
```

Comment: It doesn't work exactly as I wanted to, but I'll try to change it.
 test("duplicate ph", "duplicate phrases"); expected result: duplicate ph duplicate phrases, but is: duplicate phrases

Comment: @Adams I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting at an index of zero, you can check if everything in s1 at and after the index matches the start of s2 until there is a match or you reach the end of s1. You can then discard everything at and after the index you get in s1 when you join the strings as s2 will already start with it. This solution will be slow if the strings you very long.